# Unexpected token < in model.JSON and metadata.json

Tags: jquery, tensorflow.js

I have a model.json and metadata.json file, and I would load this in tensorflow.js, but I got this error:

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 undefined
```

I cannot find `token <` in the [JSON file](https://github.com/maximus3219/maximus3219.github.io/blob/main/TM_model/model.json).

The javascript is as follow:

```
let model;
let modelLoaded = false;
$( document ).ready(async function () {
    modelLoaded = false;
    $('.progress-bar').show();
    console.log( "Loading model..." );
    model = await tmImage.load('TM_model/model.json', 'TM_model/model.json/metadata.json');
    maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();
    console.log( "Model loaded." );
    $('.progress-bar').hide();
    modelLoaded = true;
});
```

Please help!! Thanks!

Comment: What is `tmImage`? I went through your code and can't find what it is.

Comment: first make sure the json are valid. You can use any json validator on the net. Second take a look at the browsers development tools what is send and what is returned from the load call

Comment: @yudhiesh tmImage is an API function from teachable machine, via <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>

Comment: I just directly use the model.json and the tensorflow.js code from teachable machine from google. It just can't work. Is teachable machine known NOT to work with their provided code?